# Replacing column value by NaN when another column has a certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the following data frame:

```
Month,Value1,Value2
02,1,10
03,2,2
04,3,12
```

In this Dataframe I wish to replace `Value1` by NaN each time `Value2` is < to 10. So the desired output will look as follow:

```
Month,Value1,Value2
02,1,10
03,NaN,2
04,3,12
```

I did try the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=[0])
data = data.loc[data['Value2'] < 10, 'Value1'] = np.nan
```

But unfortunately it's not working and gives me back the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Does anyone know why? and maybe how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a double assignment. Try this:

```
data.loc[data['Value2'] < 10, 'Value1'] = np.nan
```

Remember [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) can be used both as a "getter" and as a "setter". So it is perfectly natural to assign a value to `data.loc[slice1, slice2]`.